# How can I access list values using DOM in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want an array (or simple string values, if not an array) containing values in `<ul>`. My code is below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Unordered List with Disc Bullets</h2>

<ul style="list-style-type:disc">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul> 
<button onclick="changeColor()">Change</button> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor(){
        var a=document.childNodes[1].childNodes[2].childNodes[3];
        alert(a.childNodes[0]);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The values I get alerted are either undefined or [object text], while I want an array so I can access them using array[0] or something like that.

Comment: Why are you using `childNodes` and arbitary indexes instead of something maintainable like `getElementsByTagName` or `querySelector`?

Comment: just a few things: never do inline js or inline cs - both are terrible practice and lead to hard-to-maintain code, also type isn't needed anymore because html5 is a thing, indent using 4 spaces too, its clearer :)

Comment: *in `<list>`* — what? There's no such thing.

Comment: @Quentin fixed - should be in `<ul>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do with [**`querySelectorAll()`**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwivnIqX7vTUAhULQY8KHaNmC2MQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FquerySelectorAll&usg=AFQjCNGw4XxpSz-PKB1SUB1yNenuYzkpUw)

```js
function changeColor() {
  var a = document.querySelectorAll('ul li')
  console.log(a[0].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<h2>Unordered List with Disc Bullets</h2>

<ul style="list-style-type:disc">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="changeColor()">Change</button>
```

**For Nodelist array creation with li text** and `forEach()` iterate the array .Then push textContent to array `arr`

```js
function changeColor() {
var arr=[];
document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(function(a){
     arr.push(a.textContent)
  })
  console.log(arr);

}
```

```html
<h2>Unordered List with Disc Bullets</h2>

<ul style="list-style-type:disc">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="changeColor()">Change</button>
```

Comment: Why `.forEach()` instead of a regular `for` loop? They're significantly slower as far as I know.

Comment: yes..for loop is good. but i was preferred  some advance level coding.its easy way to handle without forloop.That's  why

Comment: What do you mean by "advance level coding"? `.forEach()` is not only slower but the syntax doesn't make it as clear what you're doing. In cases like this I always recommend using a regular `for` loop (of `for ... of` if you can).

Comment: @RodrigoLeite ..its means..some different syntax on same behaviour ..`forEach() has better readability than the for loop`. ..you could refer this [article](http://thejsguy.com/2016/07/30/javascript-for-loop-vs-array-foreach.html)

Comment: That article is outdated, it covers only regular `for` loops, when not only `for ... of` is a lot better in terms of performance, but it also excels at readability (`for product of products`, as opposed to `products.forEach(product => {})`). Not to mention you can't use `break`s or `continue`s using `forEach`, you have to resort to band-aids, which only make your code less readable.